# Как запустить скрипт при загрузке страницы?

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть код - `<a id="trigg" href="javascript:void(0);">Показать POP-UP окно</a>` который запускает скрипт с pop - up окном, каким образом его можно автоматизировать?
Уже второй день ищу решение проблемы в интернете, пока не чего нормального нет.

```
onload="document.location.href='http://www.google.ru'" в body не хочет открывать
```

javascript:void(0). Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: бросай ф-ю на js сюда

Comment: В head добавил <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   PopUp($('#obj'), $('#trigg'));
  });
 </script>

Comment: Найдите в скриптах, подключённых к странице, код обработчика события click у элемента с id=trigg и выложите его сюда.

Comment: Простите, не разбираюсь во всем этом. Покажу вам весь код, если вас это устроит. http://rghost.ru/39189527

Comment: @x7g100, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).@x7g100, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Пример [можно посмотреть тут](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/7UHvX/1/)

```
$('#trigg').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    // показываем окно
    $('#popup').fadeIn('slow');
    // или любая другая функция, напр.,
    // document.location.href='http://hashcode.ru';
});

$(window).load(function(){
    $('#trigg').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Простите, а как запустить этот скрипт автоматически при загрузке страницы?

Comment: А он и будет запускаться автоматически. В примере по ссылке разве не заметно? )) Ключевой код:

    $(window).load(function(){
        $('#trigg').trigger('click');
    });

Comment: Этот код что выше, его нужно заменить в теге head или в самом popup.js?
Да, у вас он автоматически запускается, у меня почему то видно только Показать POP-UP окно и ни каких дальнейших действий не происходит, видимо что - то не так делаю.

Comment: Все, получилось сделать. Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: Ну, раз получилось, то хорошо. Просто хотел добавить, чтоб поставить точку в этом вопросе, что надо добавить код в сам плагин:

    if($(trig)){
        $(window).load(function(){
            showWin();
        });
    }

P.S. @x7g100, не нужно нажимать "наградить", тем более, что у вас баллов не так много )) Достаточно нажать "палец вверх", если ответ понравился или "галочку" напротив ответа, который считаете правильным

Comment: Спасибо, все работает.