# Запуск второго pop-up окна

Tags: jquery, javascript, html

Здравствуйте, в [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/127014/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D1%8B) вопросе я спрашивал как при загрузке страницы автоматически запустить pop-up окно, мне помогли, все работает.
Уважаемые пользователи, помогите мне запустить второе такое же окно (с измененным текстом) при нажатии на кнопку.

За ранее благодарю.

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
   PopUp($('#obj'), $('#trigg'));
  });
</script>

При попытке изменить все obj на obj1 скрипт почему то не работает.

Answer (score 1):

В общем, чем мучать тот плагин (если его можно таковым считать), я сделал что-то похожее. Это всё конечно изобретение колеса, т.к. есть немерянно готовых решений. Но если вы хотите такую штучку без всяких излишеств, то плиззз - пользуйтесь [моим изобретенным колесом](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zgKMT/2/) ))

Comment: Простите, я не знал что $(document).ready(function(e) нужно вставлять. >_<

Comment: @x7g100, тут надо использовать подключение внешнего документа. И ссылки с атрибутом **target="_self"**. [В этом примере](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/zgKMT/7/), в первом окне (при подгрузке), кликните по ссылке.

Как я и предполагал, простым набором функций не обойдется )) Поэтому, предлагаю вам посмотреть на проверенный временем плагин [fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

Comment: А еще есть [плагин с пошаговой регистрацией](http://blog.webexpedition18.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/11/signup_form_WebExpedition18.zip), его [демо можно глянуть тут](http://webexpedition18.com/download/signup_form_WebExpedition18/)

Comment: Спасибо. Попробую посмотреть fancybox .

Comment: @x7g100, происходит )) Только может долго подгружаться.

Comment: а нельзя кликая по ссылке закрыть окно и открыть новое?

Comment: @x7g100, всё можно, только для того чтоб написать плагин с учетом большинства требований, надо время. И повторюсь, что очень многое уже реализовано и просто не вижу смысла тратить время на повторение.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы посоветовал плагин [JQuery Window](http://www.google.co.uz/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CGAQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Ffstoke.me%2Fjquery%2Fwindow%2F&ei=a-ECUKvlN8uN4gTWlbmJCA&usg=AFQjCNEVFh8K8gmYaHXAHY9TNcCqbn7Gxg)